# Need to highlight the today's date cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to use the simplest way to highlight the Today() date in a cell.

I have columns with dates listed from the first day of the month till the last one.

I would like to see the cell highlighted according to the TODAY() date...

Is there a simple way to achieve it?

The way I create the list is by adding a fixed date like 07/01/2023

And then I just drag it till the date I need.

Comment: When should this highlight take place? e.g. When the workbook is opened? On a specific time when a user needs it?

Comment: Just as soon as the workbook is opened. No events are attached to the highlight. Just have it highlighted permanently as much as the TODAY() happens.

Comment: What do you need to do? If you do this once and that's it, I would go @Alan's way. It is clean and simple. Just adjust the range of cells to 12 columns and 31 rows to have all the posible dates included. If you need to repeat this, then some VBA would to the word once and for all.

Answer (score 2):

I would use conditional formatting. This will also work on Excel via web (whereas VBA will not work via web) and it's simple.

Select the range of date cells, hit "Conditional Formatting", then Manage Rules, the add new rule, set the formula = `= <<FirstCellInRangeHere>> = Today()` , choose how you want to format it and that's it..

Here's a 30 second GIF to show it being applied. (Right click and open in new window if it's not clear)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in the sheet code pane

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
For Each c In UsedRange
If (c) = DateValue(Now()) Then c.Interior.Color = xlGreen
Next c
End Sub
```

Coloring is activated when the Sheet changes.

Set the color (xlGreen) to the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

There is inbuilt function called "Highlight Cells Rules" under "Conditional Formatting" in home tab. Select Full full column or particular cell then go to Home > style > Conditional formatting > Highlight Cells Rules then select "A date occurring". Select the required day then select required formatting of cell and its done.